# Processing - ScreenToWorldCoordinate function?

Tags: java, processing

I'm working on a project with Processing that requires the ability to determine whether or not the mouse is inside of a circle.  Therefore, I need to obtain the position of the circle and the position of the mouse.  However, the position of the circle has been modified using matrix functions such as `translate` and `scale`.  For example:

```
float circle_x;
float circle_y;
float circle_radius;

void setup() {
    circle_x = 10.0;
    circle_y = 17.0;
    circle_radius = 15.0;
}

void draw() {
    pushMatrix();

    /* ... arbitrary number of calls to modify the matrix ... */
    translate(THING, THING);
    scale(THING);
    translate(THING);
    /* ... */

    /* draw the circle */
    ellipse(circle_x, circle_y, circle_radius, circle_radius);

    /* now I want to detect whether or not my mouse is inside of the 
       circle.  In order to do that, I need to modify the coordinates
       of the mouse in the same fashion as circle_x and circle_y.  I'm
       hoping to do something like this: */
    float world_x = screenToWorld_X(mouseX);
    float world_y = screenToWorld_Y(mouseY);

    /* ... check if [world_x, world_y] is inside the circle ... */


    popMatrix();

}
```

Is there any way to do this in Processing?  I was looking at the documentation but I couldn't seem to find any functions.  If not, how can I achieve my goal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the **coordinates** section of [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

Specifically, you're looking for the `modelX()` and `modelY()` functions. Or you could use the `screenX()` and `screenY()` functions to go the other way and convert your world coordinates into screen coordinates.

Comment: It looks like modelX() and modelY() are meant to be used in 3D mode.  How can I get them to work using only 2D coordinates?  Do I just specify 0 for z?

Comment: Actually, it looks like `screenX()` does exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!

Comment: @David Both the model and screen functions should work in 2D or 3D. They'll just have a Z value of 0.